# Objective-c: Implement ease out animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, functional-programming

I have the code below to animate a score label. How would you go about changing it so it becomes an ease out animation?

Thanks

```
- (void)animateFrom:(float)fromValue toValue:(float)toValue
{
    self.scoreAnimationFrom = fromValue;
    self.scoreAnimationTo = self.question.correctValue;

    CADisplayLink *link = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(animateNumber:)];

    self.startTimeInterval = CACurrentMediaTime();
    [link addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void)animateNumber:(CADisplayLink *)link
{
    float dt = ([link timestamp] - self.startTimeInterval) / self.duration;

    if (dt >= 1.0)
    {
        [link removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
        return;
    }

    float current = ((self.scoreAnimationTo - self.scoreAnimationFrom) * dt + self.scoreAnimationFrom);
    self.valueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", current];
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What you posted is manual animation that changes the value of a text field based on elapsed time. What does it mean to "ease out" an animation of text values? Easing an animation out causes it to glide to a stop at it's final value. You don't have any smooth transitions to glide.

Comment: I want that the score change should be fast in the beginning and slow in the end... I guess my question has to do with how you manually create timing function on an animation

Comment: Also, please take a few minutes to tag the question properly - it has very little to do with Objective-C (just a programming language) and I fail to see any functional programming in the code you have shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The progress of your animation is described by the `dt` variable, which is a value between 0 and 1. Applying an ease out timing to your animation is as simple as funnelling this value into an appropriate timing function before applying it further. The responsibility of a timing function is to turn the original value into another value between 0 and 1, following a specific timing curve. For more information about timing functions, simply refer to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Animation_Types_Timing/Articles/Timing.html).

In your case, you therefore need to apply an ease out timing function to `dt`, something like:

```
dt = [[TimingFunction easeOutTimingFunction] solveForInput:dt];
```

Core Animation provides the `CAMediaTimingFunction` class, but sadly its `_solveForInput:` solving method is private. There exists several open-source implementations of timing functions that you can use instead, e.g. https://github.com/warrenm/AHEasing.

If you are curious, I also [recently implemented](https://github.com/defagos/CoconutKit/blob/develop/CoconutKit/Sources/Core/CAMediaTimingFunction+HLSExtensions.m) a method equivalent to `_solveForInput:` within a category of `CAMediaTimingFunction`.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a very simple solution by using a sin function instead of the complex curve calculation with polynomial coefficients:

```
//EasyOut
dt = sin(dt*M_PI/2)+0.01f;
```

Enjoy it :)